# BIRT using log4J by default

Tags: log4j, birt

do BIRT by default uses log4j.properties file?

if my aplication log4j path is same as birt log path.. then birt log is using my application log only.. i dont want this

Answer (score 1):

No, BIRT use java logging (not a log4j). Details are [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Scripting#Logging).